# Mix two lists in groovy according to a pattern in Groovy?

Tags: algorithm, collections, groovy

I have two lists lets say:

```
def list1 = [a,b,c,d,e...]
def list2 = [1,2,3,4,5... ]
```

I want them to mix in a certain pattern so that final list looks like:
`[a,b,c,d,1,2,e,f,g,h,3,4,i,j,k,l,5,6...]`

Basically after every `n` elements from list1, i get `m` elements from list2.

EDIT: If one list runs out of elements, the items in the remaining list should simply get added to the final list.

EDIT2: Both the lists can have objects as elements.

I want to find the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you do when a list has run out of elements?

Comment: I don't use groovy. Would it be help if I tell you the way in Python?

Comment: @tim_yates: i just add the items from the remaining list together

Comment: @skyler i have never worked in python :(

Comment: @AtharvaJohri So the answer below is no good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this in Groovy:

So I have a method `mix` which takes a map with Integer keys (the number of elements required), and Lists as values:

```
List mix( Map<Integer,List> amounts ) {
  amounts.collect { k, v ->
    v.collate( k )
  }.transpose().flatten()
}
```

Then, given:

```
// The letters a to z
def list1 = 'a'..'z'

// The numbers 1 to 10
def list2 = 1..10

// Call, and ask for 4 of list1 followed by 2 of list2
mix( [ 4:list1, 2:list2 ] )
```

That returns:

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2,
  'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 3, 4,
  'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 5, 6,
  'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 7, 8,
  'q', 'r', 's', 't', 9, 10 ]
```

(formatted to look better here)

As you can see, it runs out of numbers first, and when it does, the list ends.  This is because transpose stops when one list runs out of elements.

#### EDIT:

Worked out another way with Iterators (so it's lazy and won't use up more memory than is otherwise required):

```
class MixingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  private int idx = 0
  private List<Iterator> iter
  private List<Integer>  amts
  
  MixingIterator( List<List> lists, List<Integer> amounts ) {
    iter = lists*.iterator()
    int i = 0
    amts = amounts.collectMany { [ i++ ] * it }
    // OR FOR GROOVY 1.7.8
    // amts = amounts.collect { [ i++ ] * it }.flatten()
  }
  
  private void moveIdx() {
    idx = ++idx % amts.size()
  }
  
  @Override boolean hasNext() {
    iter*.hasNext().any()
  }
  
  @Override T next() {
    if( !hasNext() ) { throw new NoSuchElementException() }
    while( !iter[ amts[ idx ] ].hasNext() ) { moveIdx() }
    T ret = iter[ amts[ idx ] ].next()
    moveIdx()
    ret
  }
  
  @Override void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
  }
}
```

You call it by:

```
def list1 = 'a'..'z'
def list2 = 1..10

def ret = new MixingIterator( [ list1, list2 ], [ 4, 2 ] ).collect()
// OR FOR GROOVY 1.7.8
// def ret = new MixingIterator( [ list1, list2 ], [ 4, 2 ] ).collect { it }
```

And ret will then equal:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1, 2,
 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 3, 4,
 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 5, 6,
 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 7, 8,
 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 9, 10,
 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: i need the remaining elements too. Also, both my initial lists are huge! would doing a `collect()` be efficient?

Comment: @AtharvaJohri You're going to be making a huge list out of the two of them anyway aren't you?  I'll have a go at an iterator version, but I expect in the end you will be collecting all the values from this iterator?

Comment: So this says:

No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.collectMany() is applicable for argument types: (com.ds.core.CategoryController$_MixingIterator_closure1) values: [com.ds.core.CategoryController$_MixingIterator_closure1@4062d86f]
Possible solutions: collectAll(groovy.lang.Closure), collect(groovy.lang.Closure), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)


Both my initial lists have objects.. sorry for not being specific!

Comment: @AtharvaJohri What version of Groovy are you using?

Comment: @AtharvaJohri if it's less than 1.8.1, then change the `collectMany` line in the constructor of the Iterator to: `amts = amounts.collect { [ i++ ] * it }.flatten()`

Comment: Yes it is 1.7.8. I made the change that you specified, but this time the exception is:  Could not find which method collect() to invoke from this list:
  public java.util.Collection java.lang.Object#collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: @AtharvaJohri you're passing amounts as a list of integers yeah?

Comment: @AtharvaJohri FOUND IT!!  For groovy 1.7.8, you need to change the last line to: `def ret = new MixingIterator( [ list1, list2 ], [ 4, 2 ] ).collect { it }` ...  The zero param `collect` didn't make it into Groovy till 1.8.5

Comment: @AtharvaJohri Updated answer to show 1.7.8 alterations in comments

Answer (score 0):

I have a functional solution preserving remaining elements based on the main answer.

```
List mix( Map<Integer,List> amounts ) {
    def maxItems = amounts.collect { k, v -> v.size() }.max()
    amounts.collect { k, v ->
        def padding = maxItems - v.size()
        it.addAll((1..padding).collect { null })
        v.collate( k )
    }.transpose().flatten().grep { it }
}
```

I tested it in a simplified version to mix three lists taking one item at time. The idea is just adding padding with null objects to make all of the same length.